# mplayer subprocess not returning

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mplayer

I'm working on a raspberry pi script that plays a random sound clip folder and pauses the script while it is playing. I am having two issues with the following code

- The last second or two of the sound clip is sometimes cut off
- It never reaches the "Done talking" output

Any tips on how to improve this? Thanks

```
import time
import subprocess
import random
import os

def talk() :
    print("Talking")

    # Get random sound clip
    soundclip = random.choice(os.listdir("/home/pi/Music/C3PO_Sounds"))
    file = '/home/pi/Music/C3PO_Sounds/' + soundclip

    # Determine length of clip in seconds
    result = subprocess.Popen(['mplayer', '-vo', 'null', '-ao', 'null',
    '-frames', '0', '-identify', file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    idlength = [x for x in result.stdout.readlines() if b"ID_LENGTH" in x]
    duration = idlength[0].split(b'=')[1].strip(b'\n')

    # Play clip
    cmd = "mplayer " + file
    subprocess.Popen(cmd.split())

    # Sleep for duration of clip
    time.sleep(float(duration))
    print("Done talking")
```

Comment: Are values of float(duration) so high that it may not get to that part because of the timer.

Comment: Thanks for having a look BenT - no, none of the clips are longer than 20 seconds.

Comment: Have you printed the value of `duration`, to check that it reflects what you know about the file? Wouldn't it be easier just to wait until the `mplayer` process finishes? I suspect that the duration extracted from the file might not be very accurate.

Comment: I put a print between the subprocess line and the wait, and it didn't work. I think the delay is ok, it just isn't getting past the subprocess for some reason